# How to protect images / movies so that just registered users will be able to see them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a site where users will be able to post / see pictures and movies.

I want to force the following restrictions:
- only registered users will be able to see images / videos.
- hotlinking assets must not work.

I intend to use nginx to serve static files.

At first I though I would save both images and videos on database. It would allow me to easily control access to them. The drawbacks to this solution are:
 - database will become to big
 - it will be slower to retrieve images / videos from database than file system
 - it won't be possible for nginx serve these files.

So my question is: how can I allow access to pictures / videos just for registered users, prevent hotlinking for them and (if possible) let nginx serve these files ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You will have to configure your nginx server to use your rails application for authentication.

Hope this helps: [Serving protected static content using nginx for speed and Rails server for authentication](https://coderwall.com/p/o0alkq/serving-protected-static-content-using-nginx-for-speed-and-rails-server-for-authentication)

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for.